# Solving first-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this first-order differential equation,I don't have any idea which type this is.. 
$$ y' +(x-y)^{2}=0$$
I have $y' +x^2 -2xy+y^2=0,\\t'+t(\frac{1}{x} -2x) +t^2x=-x$  and then I divide by $x^2$ and replace $\frac{y}{x}=t$ , so I have then $$ $$
It seems like it's a Riccati's diff. equation,but I don't know how to do it beacuse I don't have any particular solution..

On Wolfram Alpha solution is $$ y=\frac{1}{c_1 e^{2ix}+\frac{i}{2}}+x+i$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $$x-y=u$$ then we get
$$1-u'=y'$$ and our equation will be $$1-u'+u^2=0$$